# Script Oracle tables (DDL) with data insert statements into single/multiple sql files

Tags: oracle, insert, schema, export, ddl

I am needing to export the tables for a given schema, into DDL scripts and Insert statements - and have it scripted such that, the order of dependencies/constraints is maintained.

I came across this article suggesting how to archive the database with data - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_archiving_data_in_file_structures.htm - not sure if the article is applicable for oracle 10g/11g.

I have seen "export table with data" features in "Sql Developer", "Toad for Oracle", "DreamCoder for Oracle" etc, but i would need to do this one table at a time, and will still need to figure out the right order of script execution manually.

Are there any tools/scripts that can utilize oracle metadata and generate DDL script with data?

Note that some of the tables have CLOB datatype columns - so the tool/script would need to be able to handle these columns.

P.S. I am needing something similar to the "Generate Scripts" feature in SQL Server 2008, where one can specify "script data" option and get back a self-sufficient script with DDL and data, generated in the order of table constraints. Please see: http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-script-data-with-generate-script-wizard.aspx

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, recognise that this isn't necessarily possible. A view can use a function in a package that also selects from the view. Another issue is that you might need to load data into tables and then apply constraints, even though this might be slower than the other way round.

In short, you will need to do some work here.

Work out the dependencies in your system. ALL_DEPENDENCIES is the primary mechanism.

Then use DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL to extract the DDL statements. For small data volumes, I'd extract the constraints separately for applying after the data load.

In current versions you can create [external tables to unload data](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=325) from regular tables into OS files (and obviously go the other way round). But if you've got exotic datatypes (BLOB, RAW, XMLTYPEs, User Defined Types....) it will be more challenging.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use Oracle standard export and import (exp/imp) here, is there a reason why you won't consider it?  Note in addition you can use the "indexfile" option on the import to output the SQL statements (unfortunately this doesn't include the inserts) to a file instead of actually executing them.